# Validation of ViewState MAC failed and Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

I know there are at least 20 questions related to "Validation of ViewState MAC failed", but mine is a bit unique (at least i think it is)

My website was working fine before I had introduced this code on code-behind of my master page.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

This obviously brings a section of a page into view after postback. After adding this code my website starting giving me "Validation of ViewState MAC failed" exception on click of a button which calls the following JS code.

```
function SelectorSubmitOld(targetUrl) {
    var f = jQuery('form').get(0);

    jQuery("#__VIEWSTATE").remove();

    f.action = targetUrl;
    f.submit();
}
```

As soon as I comment the code written in code-behind of MasterPage, everything comes back to normal.

The following I tried other than the above mentioned (which was obviously not required)

- My application is hosted on just 1 server
- Machinekey is present in web.config and removing/changing it did not solve my problem
- Setting EnableViewStateMAC=false in web.config or at page level did not solve my problem

My question is, I am unable to understand what is the relation between my code and ViewStateMAC?

Please let me know if you need any further information from my side.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Web Forms (.aspx) pages are meant only to post back to themselves, not to any other page.  In your case, you have A.aspx posting to B.aspx by changing the <form action> parameter at submission time.

What's the scenario you're trying to accomplish by changing the POST URL dynamically?  Perhaps we can suggest a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121505/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111407-1.aspx), I would try to remove references to postback posiiton with :

```
function SelectorSubmitOld(targetUrl) {
    var f = jQuery('form').get(0);

    jQuery("#__VIEWSTATE").remove();
    jQuery("#__SCROLLPOSITIONX").remove();
    jQuery("#__SCROLLPOSITIONY").remove();

    f.action = targetUrl;
    f.submit();
}
```